# rails 3 customize validator error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following Ryan Bates' Railscast. I find when I tried to establish my customized field validator, my rails 3 is not working as expected.

I established a new email_format_validator.rb file in under lib/ and the codes are:

```
class EmailFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not formatted properly") 
    end
  end
end
```

I put this line in my user.rb (Model file):

```
validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :email_format=>true
```

The browser complained:

Unknown validator: 'email_format'

Why? How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put 'email_format_validator.rb' under 'config/initializers'. And then restart the server. Everything is working now..

Answer (score 4):

You will need to restart your server. The `lib` directory isn't loaded by default, so you'll need to restart your Rails server in order to load this validator.

**Edit:**

Try putting them under `lib/validators` and restarting the server...

Comment: I am sorry, but this is still not working.... I tried to put it under 'config/initializers'. And It is working now..