# validates_email_format_of throws Unknown validator: 'EmailFormatValidator' in rails 4 engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I am using rails 4, and I am I creating an engine. In this engines `.gemspec` I did the following:

```
  s.add_dependency "rails", "~> 4.0.3"
  s.add_dependency 'pg'
  s.add_dependency 'bcrypt-ruby'
  s.add_dependency 'validates_email_format_of' #Hi I am right here

  s.add_development_dependency 'rspec-rails'
  s.add_development_dependency 'letter_opener'
  s.add_development_dependency 'pry'
  s.add_development_dependency 'pry-rails'
  s.add_development_dependency 'database_cleaner'
  s.add_development_dependency 'capybara'
  s.add_development_dependency 'factory_girl_rails'
```

I followed these [instructions on installing](https://github.com/alexdunae/validates_email_format_of#installation) `validates_email_format_of` and the `bundle install` worked. How ever when I run `bundle exec rspec` I get the error:  `Unknown validator: 'EmailFormatValidator'`

My Model Looks Like this:

```
require 'bcrypt'

module Xaaron
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :password

    before_save :encrypt_password

    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :user_name, uniqueness: true, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
    validates :email, presence: true, confirmation: true, uniqueness: true, email_format: {message: "Email Invalid"}, if: :new_record?
    validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, length: { minimum: 10 }, if: :new_record?

    def self.authenticate_user(user_name, password)
        user = Xaaron::User.find_by(user_name: user_name)
        if(user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.salt))
            user
        else
            nil
        end
    end

    def encrypt_password
        if password.present?
            self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
            self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

See nice and simple, the line `validates :email, presence: true, confirmation: true, uniqueness: true, email_format: {message: "Email Invalid"}, if: :new_record?` is whats throwing the error. Now the docs state to use `:email_format => {message: 'asdasdsad'}` But no matter how the syntax is, I get that error.

Thoughts?

Comment: You are using a very old gem, just to note it. Why not just validate against a regex, like:   VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A(|(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})\z/i

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is add

```
require 'validates_email_format_of'
```

to the top of your file and you should be able to use the gem like normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the example included on [Ruby on Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates).

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors.add attribute, (options[:message] || "is not an email") unless
      value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
  end
end

validates :email, presence: true, email: true
```

Or simply do this:

```
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your rails server to re-load the validators:

```
rails server
```

Reference: [rails 3 customize validator error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870916/rails-3-customize-validator-error)